# Merging results on a joined table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how would I go about merging the results on the joined table if the model_name and model match?

Table: tw

```
model
customer_name
```

Table: model

```
model_name
quantity
```

SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT model.model_quantity, model.model_name, tw.customer_name, tw.model FROM tw
RIGHT OUTER JOIN model
ON model.model_name=tw.model
AND tw.completed = 1 AND tw.stock = 0
ORDER BY model.id
```

I have displayed the array information as display purposes in hope it will help make sense of how the merge needs to happen.

Currently:

```
STC5
0
Andy Baker
Array ( [model_quantity] => 0 [model_name] => STC5 [customer_name] => Andy Baker [model] => STC5 ) 

STC5
0
Richard Cash
Array ( [model_quantity] => 0 [model_name] => STC5 [customer_name] => Richard Cash [model] => STC5 )
```

Intended results one column with list of all names of matching models:

```
STC5
0
Andy Baker
Richard Cash
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results as *tables*?  That would help convey what you want to do.

Comment: How would it look if different customers have the same model but different quantities?

Comment: I believe what I need to do is to check to see if the last "model_name" is the same before continuing the loop, if it is the same it needs to call the "customer_name" again, if the next is a different model_name it continues the loop as normal.

Comment: The model and quantities will be the same, only the customer name changes, the customer is assigned a model number and then their name is displayed under the model.